# How to search words in richtextbox with different orders(up and down)?

Tags: c#, search, user-interface, direction

Like I want to search 'test' from the beginning of the sentence or the end of the sentence, how to make it work? What method should i use? I will type "test" in a textbox, and search in the richtextbox, the sentence is in richtextbox. Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch() to check for certain text string in a larger text string:

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("text string including test", "test", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    //test found
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think my problem is the search direction, so do you mean the Regex.RightToLeft ?